AWS Bedrock Runtime Syntax -- What's Missing in This Syntax?
I'm working on calling an AWS Bedrock Model from my node.js code.
I copied the PHP code for this from this SO post, and transformed it into this node.js code:
import {BedrockRuntimeClient, InvokeModelCommand} from "@aws-sdk/client-bedrock-runtime";

const awsBedrockClient = new BedrockRuntimeClient({
    region: "us-east-1",
    credentials: credentials
});

        const modelId = 'amazon.nova-lite-v1:0';

        const body = {
            prompt: prompt,
            max_tokens_to_sample: 1000,
            temperature: 0.5,
            top_k: 250,
            top_p: 1,
            stop_sequences: [
                "\n\nHuman:"
            ],
        };

        async function invokeModel() {
            // Initialize the Bedrock client
            const payload = {
                contentType: 'application/json',
                accept: '*/*',
                body: JSON.stringify(body),
                modelId: modelId,
            };

            try {
                const command = new InvokeModelCommand(payload);
                const response = await awsBedrockClient.send(command);
                return response;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data from AI:', error);
            }
        }

        invokeModel()
            .then(chatCompletion => console.log(result))
            .catch(error =>
                console.error('Error fetching data from AI:', error));

I'm getting this error:

required key [messages] not found, please reformat your input and try again.

I've tried this:
    const body = {
        messages: [
            {
                role: "user",
                content: prompt
            }
        ],
        max_tokens_to_sample: 1000,
        temperature: 0.5,
        top_k: 250,
        top_p: 1,
        stop_sequences: [
            "\n\nHuman:"
        ],
    };

... and get this error:

extraneous key [top_p] is not permitted, please reformat your input and try again.

I followed that and got messages telling me to remove all the other keys except for messages.
I removed them and got this:

Malformed input request: #/messages/0/content: expected type: JSONArray, found: String, please reformat your input and try again.

I've wrestled with that one too, but I haven't found the solution. What am I missing?
UPDATE
I haven't figured out how to get amazon.nova-lite-v1:0 working yet, but I did get anthropic.claude-3-haiku-20240307-v1:0 working with the help of this YouTube video.
It appears that every one of these models, has a different set of keys it wants sent to it -- and that there's no single place you can go to find out what the required keys are for each model.
Here's the code for getting anthropic.claude-3-haiku-20240307-v1:0 to work:
    const payload = {
        messages: [
            {
                role: "user",
                content: [
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "text": prompt
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        max_tokens: 1000,
        temperature: 0.1,
        anthropic_version: "bedrock-2023-05-31"
    };

   const command = new InvokeModelCommand({
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
        contentType: "application/json",
        accept: "application/json",
        modelId,
    });

    try {
        const response = await awsBedrockClient.send(command);
        const decodedResponseBody = new TextDecoder().decode(response.body);

        /** @type {ResponseBody} */
        const responseBody = JSON.parse(decodedResponseBody);

        responseFromAI = responseBody.content[0].text;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error fetching data from AI:', error);
    }

